# SQL Server with Unity3D

Tags: c#, sql-server, unity-game-engine

I want to use SQL Server with Unity. I add `System.Data.dll` to assets in Unity project but I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'SqlClient' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Then I added `sqlclient.dll` to the assets folder, but I still get:

> The type name 'SqlConnection' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>   Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

Please help me! What's wrong?

Comment: Are you tried to [copy libraries from Unity folder and sent needed .NET compability level](https://answers.unity.com/questions/29293/compiler-error-with-mysql-connection-in-unity-3-sy.html)?

Comment: plz more details about how i do copy that ?

Comment: @eman he gave you a link with the exact answer (if that is your problem)

Answer (score 2):

After some researches, looks like there are much easy way to import sql in new versions of Unity:

1. Download new System.Data.SqlClient from nuget. For example, use in
   terminal `nuget install System.Data.SqlClient -Version 4.7.0
   -OutputDirectory <some temp dir>`
2. Open unity build settings, find `Api Compatibility Level`. It will be `.NET 4.x` or `.NET Standard 2.0`
3. Create `Plugins` directory in folder
4. Copy dll from `<some temp dir>/lib/<api level>/System.Data.SqlClient.dll` to `Plugins` directory.
5. That all, you can use sql :)

For example, in my case there are `.NET Standard 2.0` compat. level and `<some temp dir>/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Data.SqlClient.dll` library.

Comment: thx very much .. but after that unity compiler  give me that error :SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

are you know the reason ?

Comment: @eman no, i didn't check real connection for this research, only research how to connect library. in my case, i catch error like "platform not supported" when tried to init connection (on Ubuntu). few years ago i used SQLite and it works fine on standalone/mobile - can propose research this tool also.